# Will studying Euclidean Number Theory (Books 7 through 9) be of any use before studying modern Elementary Number Theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, euclidean-geometry

I was long thinking about seriously studying number theory, and while I'm still reading Euclid's Elements, I was wondering if reading through book 7 through 9 (which is Euclidean Number Theory) is of any use before studying actual (modern) number theory. I've already read book 7, which introduced the Euclidean Algorithm and an algorithm to find the Least Common Multiple of two or more numbers (which was already properly introduced to me before). I would like to know if my soon-to-develop knowledge of Euclidean Number Theory will be of any help in my future study of Elementary Number Theory, emphasis on elementary. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depends on what you are interested in. If you wanted to learn Elementary Number Theory quickly, I'd have said it was better to read modern sources, as they emphasize arithmetic and algebraic techniques.  But Euclid is always worth reading for its own sake.

Comment: Only if you have a strong interest in the *history* of elementary number theory (and you should first learn from modern expositions since they have the benefit of many centuries of profound insight).